# How to select an option from a select menu from a script?

Tags: shell-script

I'm working on a script to automate a fill tasks that I do hundreds of times a day, such as building iOS/Android projects, but I'm not very experienced with shell scripting.

In one of the projects, we're using Titanium, which gives me a CLI wrapper around the native build commands, so I do:

`titanium build -p ios -T device` to deploy it on my device, but before deploying, I need to select a few things, so I get this:

```
Which developer certificate would you like to use?
/Users/bernardo/Library/Keychains/login.keychain
   1)  CERTIFICATE 1 (xxx)  (expires Oct 16, 2015  4:27:51 pm)
   2)  CERTIFICATE 2 (xxx)  (expires Oct  1, 2015 12:06:30 pm)
Select a certificate by number or name:
```

I always select the very same options, so the question is: how do I create a script that will automatically select option `1` every time?

Thanks!

EDIT:

So I tried to use `expect` to select the option. After googling around, I'm doing it like this:

`expect <<EOD
heredoc> spawn titanium build -p ios -T device
heredoc> expect "Select a certificate by number or name"
heredoc> send "1\r"
heredoc> EOD`

However, instead of sending "1" as input, it shows a "%" instead. Anyone know why?

Comment: The easest way is to change the invoke script which call the `select` command`. Do you have access to it?

Comment: @Costas Technically yes, but this is part of an open source project my whole team is working with, so changing the script locally wouldn't be ideal in our case, as we need to keep all the files up to date with the repo... Any other ideas?

Comment: Put inside some check `if [ "$USER" = "Bernardo Oliveira" ] ; then <your choice> ; else select <from main script> ; fi`

Comment: Does this command `titanium build -p ios -T device` read anything else from the terminal? If not, you should be able to pipe the desired option to it.

Comment: @PM2Ring It does, actually. After asking me for the certificate to use, it asks me to select a provisioning profile, also from a select menu.

Comment: That should still be ok. Try piping in your option using echo. Eg, `echo 1|titanium build -p ios -T device`. And if your provisioning profile selection is also a constant, you could pipe that in as well, eg `echo -e "1\n2"|titanium build -p ios -T device`.

Comment: And if that works, you could supply that option data from a file using file redirection. Eg, `titanium build -p ios -T device < myopts` where myopts is a file containing the option numbers, one per line.

Comment: You could also look into **[expect](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Expect)** and autoexpect: http://expect.sourceforge.net/example/autoexpect.man.html

Comment: @goldilocks thanks for the tip! I tried using expect and it almost works, but not exactly. I added more info to the post. Any tips will be highly appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Maybe you should also consider modifying that script to take a command line argument for this. This would probably be somewhat easier than trieing all this with `select`. Also, I'm not sure wether this matters, but your `select` is lacking the last `:`.

Comment: @Sebb can you clarify, please? Modify the `expect` script? To take what argument? Sorry if it's an obvious thing, it's my first try with `expect`, I don't really know good practices or how to do it. And it's working well without the last `:`. Actually, I doesn't work with the `:` for some reason.

Comment: @BernardoOliveira Maybe my answer isn't clear enough, I'm not a native speaker. My answer is an extension of @costas suggestion to modify the asking script. I suggested edit it to take a command line argument for the selects instead of checking for your computer and selecting therfore so you could invoke it with for example `$ ./my.script --certificate ~/my.cert`. This could aid other developers of your project too, so it should be okay.